# Visualiser in MATSim

Tags: java, transport

I am Master's student in Transportation and trying to use MATSim for traffic simulation.
I am using it with Linux and eclipse IDE.. I completed the steps upto running the sample project as java application.
http://matsim.org/node/599#startVisualizer

But I want to visualise the data using the visualiser mentioned there..but no steps are given how to launch the visualiser jar file..
3.4. Start the Visualizer
It bluntly says launch the visulaiser..i don't know java..but i tried to launch the visualiser as

```
java -jar via-app-1.5.1.jar
```

but it ends as

```
Could not find the main class: com.senozon.via.Via.
```

Answer (score 1):

the linux distribution of Via should come with a shell script (simply called `via`). Just run that:

```
./via
```

to start the visualizer.